# Run CMD/Powershell command before the build command?

Tags: intellij-idea

How I can run a CMD/Powershell before my Java GUI Application will be build and invoked.

I want run the command: `sass ANYFILE.scss:ANYFILE.css` to compile my scss file first.

In the Run/Debug Configurations I found nothing which helps me at the `Before launch` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html) in IDE which will run any command you want, then add it in **Before launch** section.
2. There is a [PowerShell plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10249-powershell) that provides a run configuration to run powershell scripts. You can add it as **Before launch** option as well.